# Identify the most central nodes in a network (using Networkx)

Tags: python, networkx

I am trying to generate subgraphs looking at specific nodes. Specifically, I would like to see, using a different colors and labels, only those nodes that have high degree centrality or betweenness centrality in my graph. It would be ok to use a Zachary's Karate Club model for example (my graph is undirected).

For calculating the degree centrality and betweenness I am using the following functions (in NetworkX):

```
degCent = nx.degree_centrality(G)
betCent = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True, endpoints=True)
```

My graph is made of approximately 5000 nodes (so not a huge graph) and I would be interested only in the top 10 nodes based on degree and betweenness centrality, just to see who these nodes are connected with and where they are located within then graph.

My approach would be to select the top 10 nodes based on degree centrality and betweenness centrality assigning a different color (green if they are in the top 10 of degree/betweenness centrality list; otherwise red), filtering the nodes within the network to select only those ones of interest (assigning them also a label, just to see where they are located in the network).

Any help and suggestion will be absolutely welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to do what you described. First, let's generate a random graph with `fast_gnp_random_graph` to illustrate the process.  From there, you can compute the degree centrality measure and the betweeness centrality measure with `nx.degree_centrality` and `nx.betweenness_centrality`. Because you are interested in only the top 10 nodes for each of these measures, you can sort the results in descending order and keep the first 10 items. Note that the top 10 degree nodes can be different than your top 10 betweeness nodes. Once you have found your top 10 nodes for each measure, you can associate a color to the node. Below, the nodes are `lightsteelblue` if they are not part of any top 10, `tab:orange` if they are only part of the top 10 degree centrality, `tab:blue` if they are only part of the top 10 betweeness centrality and `tab:green` if they are part of both top 10s. Finally, you can plot the result and set up a legend.
See code below:

```py
import networkx as nx
from networkx.generators import *
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

N_nodes=50
G=fast_gnp_random_graph(N_nodes,p=0.1,seed=0)

#Computing centrality
degCent = nx.degree_centrality(G)

#Descending order sorting centrality
degCent_sorted=dict(sorted(degCent.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))

#Computing betweeness
betCent = nx.betweenness_centrality(G, normalized=True, endpoints=True)

#Descending order sorting betweeness
betCent_sorted=dict(sorted(betCent.items(), key=lambda item: item[1],reverse=True))

#Color for regular nodes
color_list=N_nodes*['lightsteelblue']

#Getting indices on top 10 nodes for each measure
N_top=10
colors_top_10=['tab:orange','tab:blue','tab:green','lightsteelblue']
keys_deg_top=list(degCent_sorted)[0:N_top]
keys_bet_top=list(betCent_sorted)[0:N_top]

#Computing centrality and betweeness intersection
inter_list=list(set(keys_deg_top) & set(keys_bet_top))

#Setting up color for nodes
for i in inter_list:
  color_list[i]=colors_top_10[2]

for i in range(N_top):
  if keys_deg_top[i] not in inter_list:
    color_list[keys_deg_top[i]]=colors_top_10[0]
  if keys_bet_top[i] not in inter_list:
    color_list[keys_bet_top[i]]=colors_top_10[1]

#Draw graph
pos= nx.circular_layout(G)
nx.draw(G,pos,with_labels=True,node_color=color_list)

#Setting up legend
labels=['Top 10 deg cent','Top 10 bet cent','Top 10 deg and bet cent','no top 10']
for i in range(len(labels)):
  plt.scatter([],[],label=labels[i],color=colors_top_10[i])
plt.legend(loc='center')
plt.show()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Below is the result of the same method applied to the Zachary's Karate Club dataset. Only the first two lines of the code change. I replaced

```py
N_nodes=50
G=fast_gnp_random_graph(N_nodes,p=0.1,seed=0)
```

with

```py
G = nx.karate_club_graph()
N_nodes=G.number_of_nodes()
```

And the output gives:

[image]

Comment: thank you jyllis. May I ask you in case of nodes with strings, not numbers, how to iterate here: `color_list[keys_deg_top[i]]=colors_top_10[0]`?

Comment: I think it should work pretty much the same. The only difference I see is that after sorting your centrality measures you will need to map the label of your node back to the original index of the node in the graph and use that index to set the color of your node. If that doesn't work, perhaps using [`set_node_attributes`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.classes.function.set_node_attributes.html) would help